# Ресурс был заблокирован из-за несоответствия MIME-типа («text/html») (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: wordpress, mime-type

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать с ошибкой:

Ресурс с «http://acme/wp-content/themes/acmejs/parallax-slider/modernizr.custom.28468.js?ver=5.8.1» был заблокирован из-за несоответствия MIME-типа («text/html») (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: Отдавать ресурс с правильным mime-type. Видимо настроить веб-сервер

Comment: Скрипт должен запускаться с mime `text/javascript`. Правьте свой код там, где вы запускаете этот скрипт.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вот, что выводится в консоли <script type="text/javascript" src="http://acme/wp-content/themes/acmejs/parallax-slider/modernizr.custom.28468.js?ver=5.8.1" id="modernizr-js"></script>